# RegEx passed by CSV file not working in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, regex, csv

Hi I have a script trying to pull out the price value from a html file. the Regex works when I assign it in the script but when I put the regex in CSV, it refuses to give me the result. Could someone help with this?

```
$htmlcontent = Get-Content ".\Temp.html" -Raw
$priceregex = "(?<=<span class=""a-offscreen"">\$)[\d\.]+"
Write-Host "Regex value is: " $priceregex
IF ($htmlcontent -match $priceregex){$Matches[0]}else{"Not found"}
$csvdata=Import-Csv .\WebMonitor-A.csv
$priceregex=$csvdata[0].Regex
Write-Host "Regex from CSV file is: " $priceregex
IF ($htmlcontent -match $priceregex){$Matches[0]}else{"Not found"}
```

The html file content looks like this:

```
<div class="a-section a-spacing-micro">                <span class="a-price aok-align-center" data-a-size="xl" data-a-color="base"><span class="a-offscreen">$10.95</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">$</span><span class="a-price-whole">10<span class="a-price-decimal">.</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">95</span></span></span>
```

I have this in CSV file as a column (Regex):

```
(?<=<span class=""a-offscreen"">\$)[\d\.]+
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/431172

Comment: @mfinni Interesting reading. a little bit over-killing. I have never seen an expert gives another solution other than giving you a correct regex, which means the other solution (XML parser?) might not be understood by most of the geeks or it's not good enough in some ways (easy,quick...etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue :**
When you give the RegEx in the Script , Certain Characters (like Quotes) must be escaped. Hence what you have given is working.

When you give the RegEx in the Textfile Eg CSV , those Characters need not be escaped.
You are still escaping those , hence that will not match.

**Solution :**
In the CSV text file , give this RegEx :

```
(?<=<span class="a-offscreen">\$)[\d\.]+
```

Here , the Quotes (around the Class Name) must not be escaped.

That will work.

Comment: Thanks, @Prem. It worked.